# Word phonetics suggestion

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

Could any English speaker recommend me the best spelling for an 'invented' word that would be pronounced something like /ˈlɛvɪ/.

As I'm no expert in phonetic symbols, those phonetic symbols are just approximate. The main concern is that the first syllable sounds more like an 'e' instead of an 'ɪ', while the second one is an 'ɪ' or 'iː', instead of an 'aɪ'.

Thanks

Comment: Did you want it to rhyme with *heavy*? There's an actual English word, *levy*, that does.

Comment: Yes, 'heavy' seems pretty accurate in pronunciation likeness. Would 'Levie' be pronounced that way too?

Comment: @PeterShor, Hi Peter, thanks for the reply. I forgot to mention you in the previous entry.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, But **Stevie** and **eerie** rhyme with **levy** and **bevy**, right? Or are those two rhyming with **sky**?

Comment: OOps! My assertion *By default the final vowel in **Levie** would be assumed to rhyme with **Stevie, eerie*** was intended to point out that we can "derive" the default for your neologism by analogy with known words sharing the relevant orthography. I don't know what I was thinking of when I included that *not **levy** and **bevy***, but I've removed that meaningless / ,misleading / incorrect comment. The *final* vowel is the same in all cases. What's different is that ***Levie*** would by default have the same "long **e**" as ***Stevie***, not the "short **e**" of ***bevy, levy, bet, red***.

Answer (score 0):

IPA shows a slightly different pronunciation than what has been suggested:

l = "L" such as in law or lie;

ɛ = "E" such as in bed or Ed;

v = "V" such as in volt or vest;

ɪ = "I" such as in bit or ick.

My spelling for the made-up word would be "LEVIH" or "LEHVIH"

Answer (score -2):

This is going to be difficult, and in the long run impossible, to express using existing patterns in English orthography.

That’s because if you mean for your word to end with the KIT vowel, then that is impossible under the rules of English [phonotactics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonotactics). That’s a checked (or lax) vowel and so cannot occur at the end of the word. Other checked vowels include those in TRAP, DRESS, STRUT, PUT.

So I’m pretty sure you want the FLEECE vowel, or if you distinguish them, the HAPPY vowel. That would be therefore not /ˈlɛvɪ/ but /ˈlɛvi/ or maybe /ˈlɛviː/ if you have phonemic length (Americans don’t).

As Peter Shor points out, we already have a word *levy* that is pronounced that way; likewise *levee*.

Even if you manage to get people to say some version which is like *lev* plus *ick* but without the *ck*, it will quickly fall back into the allowable patterns of English and end up being just *levy* (or *levee*) again to rhyme with *bevvy* (short for *beverage*) and *Chevy* (short for *Chevrolet*).

Comment: Thanks for the checked vowel explanation, didn't know about that. Let's end the word with one of those open /i/ or /i:/ sounds then. With _levy_ isn't there a 'risk' of having the first syllable pronounced as an /i/ as well? As it is the case with the brand name Levi's.

Comment: @Thomas What part of speech is this? *Levy* is a verb.

Comment: I'm wanting to use it as a name

Comment: @Thomas Oh then just call him Levvy.